# How do I remove a virtualbox machine from virtualbox manager so I can reinstall it?

Tags: virtualbox, delete

I created a vm for Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS using unattended install (my first time using VirtualBox). My Activities button is not working in Gnome, and just produces a search window instead of a menu. I'd like to delete the machine from VirtualBox and reinstall it with manual install. How do I delete the machine I just installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vboxmanage list vms
```

list all vms you have registered in virtualbox.

The 1. field is the name of your virtualmachine the second one the uuid.

To remove a vm (I prefer by name)

```
vboxmanage unregistervm vmname --delete-all
```

unregistered the virtualmachine from virtualbox and delete it complete.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks and solved.