# How to Reverse Disc Partition?

Tags: storage

I made a Disc Partition so that I could use Oracle VirtualVox to run Windows, however I no longer need it and would like to be able to use that storage again. Do you know of any way to reverse the disc partition?
P.D. I'm in Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
The partition was created when VirtualBox asked me to assign some space for the VM

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the partition was made when virtualbox asked me to dedicate some space to the virtual machine. I want to be sure that by selecting the option to delete the VM I get back my storage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a virtualbox machine from virtualbox manager so I can reinstall it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483819/how-do-i-remove-a-virtualbox-machine-from-virtualbox-manager-so-i-can-reinstall)

Comment: It did, many thanks and have a jolly good rest of your day!